# Correct VF code to show the field of account details

Tags: visualforce

what is the correct VF code to show only the 5 field in account details... i want to show the field in account details are " Account Owner,Account Name,Phone,Type, Industry,Region and billing address"

```
  <p align="right">System Date and Time is :{!$System.OriginDateTime}<br/>
   Today's current Time is:{!Now()}<br/>
   Today's full date is: {!TODAY()}<br/></p>  
                   <apex:image id="theImage" value="{!$Resource.bluebird}" width="155" height="155"/>
   <p align="left">Today's Month is: {!MONTH(TODAY())}<br/>       
   Number Day of the Month: {!DAY(TODAY())}<br/> 
   Current Year: {!YEAR(TODAY())}<br/> </p>            

                 <b><h1><font color="#FFFF00" size="-1"><marquee bgcolor="#FF4000"   scrollamount="1">
                 You are viewing the Account "{!Account.Name}" Time,Date,Days and Years of company details
                 </marquee></font></h1></b>

    <apex:detail title="true" relatedList="false" />

            <apex:relatedList list="Opportunities"/>
```

......

Comment: remove them from page layout.

Answer (score 4):

I can't see all your VF page tags but you can use the `<apex:outputfield>` to expose those fields. 
This is an example from the components visualforce page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" tabStyle="Opportunity">
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Opportunity Information">
            <apex:outputField value="{!opportunity.name}"/>
            <apex:outputField value="{!opportunity.amount}"/>
            <apex:outputField value="{!opportunity.closeDate}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

**All you need to do is to use:**

1. `<apex:outputField value="{!account.name}"/>` for the Account name.
2. `<apex:outputField value="{!account.CreatedBy.Name}"/>` for Account Owner.
3. `<apex:outputField value="{!account.Phone}"/>` for Account Phone.
4. `<apex:outputField value="{!account.Type}"/>` for Account Type.
5. `<apex:outputField value="{!account.Industry}"/>` for Account Industry, etc ..

**For the Billing Address it may be better to use something like:**

`<apex:outputField value="{!account.BillingCity}"/>`

`<apex:outputField value="{!account.BillingCountry}"/>`

`<apex:outputField value="{!account.BillingPostalCode}"/>`

`<apex:outputField value="{!account.BillingState}"/>`

`<apex:outputField value="{!account.BillingStreet}"/>`

For this example to render properly, you must associate the Visualforce page 
with a valid account record in the URL. 
For example, if 001D000000IRt53 is the account ID, the resulting URL should be: https://Salesforce_instance/apex/myPage?id=001D000000IRt53
See the Visualforce Developer's Guide Quick Start Tutorial for more information.

Comment: but how to put <apex:outputfield>  in above code

Comment: Can you add the full VF page from <b><apex:page> to </apex:page></b> please?

Comment: Starting line are <apex:page standardController="Account" rendered="true" renderAs="">
  <apex:pageBlock title="My company is {!Account.Name} and Owner is {!$User.FirstName} {!$User.LastName}">

Comment: my standard controller is Account and i want show the account details field are " Account Owner,Account Name,Phone,Type, Industry,Region and billing address".... how i will put in above code ?

Comment: I am not able paste my all vf code.. please add above line in above code. please help me

Comment: Hi(Kessel) how i put in above code

Comment: @user28787 check my initial answer for further details on how to use the`<apex:outputField>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Your fields are coming from `<apex:detail title="true" relatedList="false" />`. This means that the Page Layout is controlling what shows/doesn't show.

Simply edit the Page Layout for the object (or for the Recordtype) and the page will "magically" adjust.